# Yocto tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, yocto

I am looking for a yocto recipe to build it including its python packages with the availability of Tensorflow 2.0.

There are instructions on building from source for Linux/MacOS systems but is there anything available like a Tensorflow 2.0 yocto recipe (meta-tf maybe)?

Comment: There is [1.13](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-tensorflow/tree/recipes-framework/tensorflow/tensorflow_1.13.0.bb) support, I'm not aware of 2.0 version.

Comment: Hi abunickabhi, did you find a recipe?
The STM32MP1-DK2 board has a layer providing TensorFlow-Lite V2.0, based on the archive zip file.
Here the link: https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/meta-st-stm32mpu-ai/tree/thud/recipes-frameworks/tensorflow-lite

Comment: http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-tensorflow/
You'll also need to include meta-java and maybe some other layers... I haven't tried this myself but it looks good